# Xamarin Forms App to connect to Arduino over Bluetooth LE

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

For weeks I was struggling to create an app that connected to an arduino device over Bluetooth Low Energy (Bluetooth LE) and I finally got it working today. I am sharing the resources I found so that if someone else is struggling they can learn from my experience. The information I am sharing is for bluetooth LE only. If your device is using  bluetooth classic this will not work as they are not compatible.

Comment: Congrats on figuring this out and thanks for sharing.  Please [edit] your post to break it up into a Question and Answer so it better fits the site format.  As written it's just a question with no answer so people are less likely to find it when searching.

Comment: Jason, Thank you for the suggestion. I have reformatted the question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow is for programming _questions,_ not a blogging platform for sharing links.

Comment: I had originally posted it as a question where there was a lot of back and forth and confusion. Now that the problem is solved I have reposted it in a cleaner format for people who are having the same issues as I did, which there were a lot of people on stack over flow stuck on this.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is new to this here is some terms you will need to know. You need to use them in your program to communicate with bluetooth LE.

UART: universal asynchronous receiver-transmitter. This is the protocol that is used to send data to a device via bluetooth LE and to receive data.

GATT: Generic Attribute Profile. This defines how data will be transferred back and forth using Services and Characteristics.

This was an excellent tutorial on how to create the app:
https://www.jenx.si/2020/08/13/bluetooth-low-energy-uart-service-with-xamarin-forms/

This app will scan for BLE devices, connect to them, send data to the device, and receive data from the device. My app is for android, but it looks like the app from this tutorial will work for IOS as well.

Once I created the app I searched for the UART UUID's of my device (an Adafruit Feather Bluefruit LE). Here is the page where I found the codes for my device:
https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-feather-m0-bluefruit-le/uart-service

I found the Send and Receive UUID's from the Nordic Semiconductor website:
https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.nordic.infocenter.sdk5.v14.0.0%2Fble_sdk_app_nus_eval.html

Then in the GattIdentifiers page I replaced the generic UUID's that were entered with the UUID's for my device. Here is what my GattIdentifiers page looks like with my UUID's.

```
public class GattIdentifiers
{
    public static Guid UartGattServiceId = Guid.Parse("6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E");
    public static Guid UartGattCharacteristicReceiveId = Guid.Parse("6E400003-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E");
    public static Guid UartGattCharacteristicSendId = Guid.Parse("6E400002-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E");
    public static Guid SpecialNotificationDescriptorId = Guid.Parse("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
}
```

A note on this is to make sure you put the right UUID's with the send and receive characteristics defined in the file. I had them reversed at first which was giving me "null" results. So if they are not working try reversing them.

I hope this helps!